# How to set measure display units in Solidworks drawing?

Tags: solidworks, unit

I have already set millimeters in document propertis, nevertheless the display units are meters

[image]

Why and how to fix?

Comment: Dumb question but need to ask- is your model set to the correct units? Check your drafting standard, restart, then check for any SW updates. Then try creating a new drawing file.

Comment: I don't have any model, I just created empty drawing

Comment: my parts come out in meters when I'm not correctly connected to my VPN, meaning SW falls back on its internal default template - check your template path, and check the templates are correct and in that location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible culprits. One of them is the following.

Check in the lower right corner of your Solidworks window.
you should see

[image]

if you click on it, you should see the following menu.

[image]

You might have pressed it accidentally.